# How to correctly use react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Somewhat new to react, and liking the library, but running into all kinds of headaches with the router.

Here is my current code, question is below:

// routes.js

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory} from 'react-router';

import App from './App';
import MainLayout from './components/MainLayout';
import Home from './components/home/Home';
import Product from './components/product/Product';
import Category from './components/category/Category';
import Cart from './components/cart/Cart';
import NotFound from './components/NotFound';

export default (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route component={App} >
      <Route path='/' component={Home} />
      <Route path='/product/:productId' component={Product} />
      <Route path='/category/:catNumber' component={Category} />
      <Route path='/cart' component={Cart} />
    </Route>
    <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
  </Router>
)
```

Now, I have three major problems, which makes me think that maybe I'm just terribly misunderstanding how the router works.

1) Strange url hashes from react [http://localhost:3002/#/?_k=xv1opy], even though they shouldn't be there, as I've already set history={browserHistory}

2) Browser console warnings: "Warning: Location "/" did not match any routes" and "Warning: You cannot change ; it will be ignored." Not sure what's happening here, as I've very clearly defined the Home component to render for path='/'.

3) Probably related, but any time I change routes, the entire application reloads, clearing all my store data. Not ideal, but I think this can be fixed once I fix #1 and (especially) #2.

More information that might be useful:

// app.js render() method

```
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <Header />
    <Subheader />
    {this.props.children}
    <Footer />
  </div>
);
```

}

// index.js

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Routes from './routes';

if ( process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  window.React = React;
}

ReactDOM.render(Routes, document.getElementById('main'));
```

Anyone a bit more familiar with React who can point me in the right direction here? Been pulling my hair out for the past two days on this, and have read seemingly every guide on react-router to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your routing is a bit flawed. Try this instead:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path='/' component={App} >
    <IndexRoute component={Home} />
    <Route path='product/:productId' component={Product} />
    <Route path='category/:catNumber' component={Category} />
    <Route path='cart' component={Cart} />
  </Route>
  <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
</Router>
```

This should solve most, if not all, of your errors.

Comment: This feel, intuitively, like it should work. But I'm still getting all the same problems.

Comment: Are your dependencies updated? What version of [tag:react] and [tag:react-router] do you use?

Comment: React 0.14.8, and react-router 1.0.3.

Comment: I believe we've found the problem in that case. [tag:react-router] v1.0.3 is nearly 6 months old. Latest version is 2.4.1. `browserHistory` wasn't introduced until 2.0.0. Update your router version and try again. There's also a newer version of [tag:react]. Check your other dependencies as well. If you use **npm** you could run the command `npm outdated` to see which packages are old.

Comment: And today I learned a valuable lesson in the react ecosystem : P. Couple of other problems have cropped up, but this fixed the router issues. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help! These packages have regular updates. I suggest checking once per week or so for updates. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

my router like this

````
    {
        element: <Layout/>,
        children: [
            {
                path: "/",
                element: <Product/>
            },
            {
                path: "/dashboard",
                element: <Dashboard/>
            },
            {
                path: "/category",
                element: <Category/>
            },
            {
                path: "/register",
                element: <RegisterForm/>
            },
            {
                path: "/addProduct",
                element: <AddProductForm/>
            },
            {
                path: "/addCategory",
                element: <AddCategoryForm/>
            },
            {
                path: "/editProduct/:id",
                element: <EditProductForm/>
            }
        ]
    }

])```
````

Comment: Thank you for deciding to contribute to stackoverflow. Would you be able to rephrase your answer and add supporting comments so that your answer mentions how it solves the question?

Answer (score 0):

The Routing can be done easily type "localhost:3000/" type we can get the login page and if only get by creating a login page and other pages component

```
        import React from 'react';
        import { Component } from "react";
        import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
        import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
        import login from './components/loginpage-component';
        import signup from './components/signup-component';
        render(){
        return (
         <BrowserRouter>
             <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={login} /> 
                <Route exact path="/signup" component={signup} /> 
                <Route exact path="/live" component={live}/>
             </Switch>  
         </BrowserRouter>
         );
        }

        }
       export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. install `react-router-dom` using **yarn** or **npm**

   `yarn add react-router-dom`
2. import react-router like this

   `import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'`
3. Use it like this

   ```
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/scopes">
            <Scopes />
        </Route>
        <Route path={"/disciplines"}>
            <Disciplines />
        </Route>
        <Route path={"/fields"}>
            <Fields />
        </Route>
        <Route path={"/issues"}>
            <Issues />
        </Route>
        <Route path={"/articles"}>
            <Articles />
        </Route>
        <Route path={"/indexing"}>
            <Indexing />
        </Route>
        <Route path={"/settings"}>
            <Settings />
        </Route>
    </Switch>
   ```
4. now you can create a link to each router like this

   `<Link to="/articles">Articles</Link>`

import **Link** as:
`import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'`

Answer (score 0):

If you follow this docs https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start, It says

**Step 1:**
Move to the project folder and type
npm install react-router-dom --save

**Step 2:**
import the route files

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react;
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Switch,Route} from "react-router-dom";

import Home from './components/home/Home';
import Product from './components/product/Product';
import Category from './components/category/Category';
import Cart from './components/cart/Cart';

const App = () => {
 return (
  <div>

   <Router>
    <Switch>

      <Route exact path="/">
        <Home />
      </Route>
      //by providing exact attribute will only match if the path matches the exact location else if we don't provide it will never render other components because it renders the first one that matches the current URL 
      <Route path="/product">
       <Product />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/category">
       <Category />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/cart">
       <Cart />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
   </Router>

 </div>
)
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to create the React Element, use element:

   `<Route path="/about" element={<About/>} />`
2. Otherwise use Component and React Router will create the React Element for you:

   `<Route path="/about" Component={About} />`

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
    
import Home from './components/Home';
import Create from './components/Create';
import Read from './components/Read';
import Update from './components/Update';

export default function App() {
  return (
     <Router>
         <Routes>
            <Route path='/' Component={Home} />
            <Route path='/create' Component={Create} />
            <Route path='/read' Component={Read} />
            <Route path='/update' Component={Update} />
         </Routes>
     </Router>
  )
}
```