# How do you use Routes and children Route elements from react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I tried running the code below and got this error:

> Uncaught Error: [Login] is not a  component. All component children of  must be a  or <React.Fragment>

I thought I was using `<Route>` elements as the children of `<Routes>`. I'm not sure what's going on.

```js
import './App.css';
import Homepage from './components/Homepage/Homepage';
import Login from './components/Login/Login';
import Register from './components/Register/Register';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState } from 'react';

export const App = () => {
  const [user, setLoginUser] = useState({});
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className='App'>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path='/'>
            {user && user._id ? <Homepage setLoginUser={setLoginUser} /> : <Login setLoginUser={setLoginUser}/>
            }
          </Route>
          <Route path='/login'>
            <Login setLoginUser={setLoginUser}/>
          </Route>
          <Route path='/register'>
            <Register />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
   </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to correctly use react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37521557/how-to-correctly-use-react-router)

Answer (score 0):

Since the new versions of react-router-dom you have the option to add components in one line for example:
`<Route path="/login" element={<Login setLoginUser={setLoginUser} />} />`
you can also add props inside the login

Here is the full code:

```
import './App.css';
import Homepage from './components/Homepage/Homepage';
import Login from './components/Login/Login';
import Register from './components/Register/Register';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState } from 'react';

export const App = () => {
  const [user, setLoginUser] = useState({});
  return (
     <BrowserRouter>
      <div className='App'>
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/"
            element={
              user && user._id ? (
                <Homepage setLoginUser={setLoginUser} />
              ) : (
                <Navigate to="/login" replace={true} />
              )
            }
          />
          <Route path='/login' element={<Login setLoginUser={setLoginUser} />} />
          <Route path='/register' element={<Register />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>  
);
};
```

I hope this answers your question